# Programmatically setting the dock:name Java Mac OS X JVM property

Tags: java, macos, operating-system, dock

Is there a programatic alternative to setting the dock:name Java Mac OS X property by doing

```
java -Xdock:name="My App Name" -jar myapp.jar
```

, or is this the only way to set the dock:name property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been a while, but I believe you need to do the following (this is assuming you're using Swing):

1. Put your `main()` method in a separate class from the JFrame.
2. Before creating the JFrame, set the "com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name" system property.

For example:

```
public class Launcher {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Hello World!");
    JFrame jframe = new MyJFrame();
    jframe.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hah -- looks like I answered this question a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307024/native-swing-menu-bar-support-for-macos-x-in-java

Comment: Looks like this is no longer working on newer versions of OS X and/or Java. It gets ignored for me on Java 1.7 and 1.8 on OS X 10.9. The `-Xdock:name` option to the `java` command seems to be the replacement technique.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple extensions are documented here: 
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/overview-summary.html

I looked at `com.apple.eawt.Application`, which gives you access to the icon and menus... but not title, unfortunately.

I am guessing the prescribed approach is to roll out your own App Bundle, as detailed here: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html