# How would I go about changing the hover text over icon in doc? (Java)

Tags: java, macos, icons, dock

Okay. I have a gui with a title called "My Java Application". When I minimize it to my doc and hover over the icon, it just says "java", not "My Java Application".
How would I fix that?

P.S.
I am using a Macintosh computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's apparently a command line option for this on the Mac:

```
-Xdock:name="YourNameHere"
```

There's also some more information here:

- [Programatically setting the dock:name Java Mac OS X JVM property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553941/programatically-setting-the-dockname-java-mac-os-x-jvm-property)
- [Native Swing Menu Bar Support For MacOS X In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307024/native-swing-menu-bar-support-for-macos-x-in-java)

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty sure I know where to put that.

Comment: Eh, I don't know why, but it doesn't seem to work. IDK. I think that my program is just screwed up, LOLZ ...

Comment: Have you tried setting the system property instead (in the main thread, before you have a GUI, if at all): `System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "YourNameHere");`? And have you tried a simple "Hello, World!" style application to rule out that your app is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the app if it's running
2. Open the app location in Finder. Right click icon in Doc - Choose Options/Show in Finder.
3. Right click the App and rename to the new name
4. Remove the app from the doc. Right click icon in Doc, Options/Remove from Doc
5. Click on the app to launch from the finder window.
6. The new app icon when launched - will have the new name as the hover text
7. Right click the app icon, choose Options and Select Keep in Doc. Position the icon to your convenient location
8. Close the app and mouse over the icon and watch the new name appearing as hover text