# Adding MenuBar Space on Mac

Tags: java, macos, whitespace

On a PC, this issue would not arise, but I have a mac and the java menu bars typically appear on the top left hand area of the screen.  For example (from the apple developers website):

[image]

The blue highlighted menu is the same name as the main class in a java program.  I was wondering how I could name my main method class with a space in between two words rather than an underscore.

Comment: It's not your main method that determines this. If you look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/java/conceptual/java14development/07-nativeplatformintegration/nativeplatformintegration.html), it can be changed via the -Xdock command line parameter or from within the plistfile

Comment: You could also look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553941/programatically-setting-the-dockname-java-mac-os-x-jvm-property)

Answer (score 1):

I tried...

- Using the `-Xdock:name="My App Name"` on the command line
- `System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Not My Mac App");` within the `main` method before before and after setting the look and feel

Only `-Xdock:name` worked.

Tested using Java 8 on 10.9.4, so the settings might be different for earlier version of Java and OS combinations

You may also consider creating a proper Mac .app bundle, which should allow you to set these properties via the `plist` file...

Take a look at [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html).  It is "slightly" out of date, but should lead you in the right direction

Comment: How do I specify in the command line which java project to do the -xdock:name to? Or does it automatically rename the project thats already open?

Comment: Thanks for your reply though. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: The command line is applied to the program you are trying to run