# Java error: "Unrecognized option: -Xdock:name=ApplicationName"

Tags: java, ant

When I run my Java app using Ant, I get this error:

```
[java] Unrecognized option: -Xdock:name=ApplicationName
[java] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
[java] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
[java] Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this parameter [is MacOSX specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553941/programatically-setting-the-dockname-java-mac-os-x-jvm-property). For example, when starting some program on a Windows JVM using this parameter, I get the same error.

Comment: I think that the source that i am using where developped using a mac. But i am currently on ubuntu. Is there any solutions ?

Comment: @user3347598: Well a simple solution may be just to remove it. Otherwise you can parametrize your ant script so that option only used with OS X.