# com.apple.mrj.application Missing for Native Swing Menu Bar support for MacOS X Snow Leopard

Tags: java, macos, swing

I was trying to define a custom name as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307024/native-swing-menu-bar-support-for-macos-x-in-java), but there is no application package in my com.apple.mrj. Is this a known issue? how can I workaround this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to show a custom name on Mac OS X is to use the `-Xdock` option of `java`.

```
java -Xdock:name=CustomName ...
```

You can see more details using the command `java -X`. You might also look at [OSXAdapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html), which puts "preferences, about, and quit functionality into handlers for the Mac OS X application menu."