# SWT on Mac OS X: Change dock program name

Tags: java, macos, swt

I have a Java SWT program on Mac OS X that always shows 'java' when the mouse hovers over the dock icon. Is there a way to change 'java' to a more suitable program name?

Comment: See also this possible duplicate: [com.apple.mrj.application Missing for Native Swing Menu Bar support for MacOS X Snow Leopard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351963/com-apple-mrj-application-missing-for-native-swing-menu-bar-support-for-macos-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by a system property:

```
-Xdock:name=AppName
```