# Changing java webstart hover text over OSX Mavericks dock icon

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start

I have a java webstart, after starting it up and hovering over the java icon in the osx dock, "java" is displayed rather than my application name.

I am already doing this:

```
System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "MyApplication");
```

and adding

```
-Xdock:name=MyApplication
```

to my vm args.  This was working fine before we upgraded to OSX Mavericks, thats when we started seeing "java".  Users who have not upgraded to mavericks yet still see the applicationName when they hover over in the dock.

I've searched but haven't found any suggestions other than the above 2.

This may be a dupe of

[SWT on Mac OS X: Change dock program name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947595/swt-on-mac-os-x-change-dock-program-name)

and

[How would I go about changing the hover text over icon in doc? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178252/how-would-i-go-about-changing-the-hover-text-over-icon-in-doc-java)

but haven't been able to resolve in Mavericks.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you switch to use Oracle Java 7 instead of Apple Java 6 as part of the upgrade?

Comment: Was already on java 7 before the upgrade.

Comment: And you are sure that it was Java 7 that your application was launched with?

Comment: I'm reasonably confident.  The jnlp specifies java 1.7+ and all users have java 7 installed on their machines.  Also confident it was java 7 being used prior to Mavericks upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [`CFBundleName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1) in your application's `Info.plist`. Some related links are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513), and this complete [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net) displays the name on OS X 10.9 using Java 7.

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>RobotChase</string>
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you put Info.plist in a webstart app?

Comment: In the application bundle, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513).

Comment: And where is the application bundle in a webstart app?

Comment: The application bundle is a hierarchical directory containing the JARs and other artifacts identified in the `.jnlp`