# Putting JMenu on the Mac menu bar

Tags: java, macos, swing, jmenu

I'm creating an java application on a Mac that uses Swing `JMenu`s. I would like to use the menu bar on the top of the screen, but it keeps on putting the menu bar in the frame itself. How do you move the menu bar to the top of the screen on a Mac?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Native Swing Menu Bar Support For MacOS X In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307024/native-swing-menu-bar-support-for-macos-x-in-java)

Comment: strange, my (slightly old, OSX 10.5 running) Apple laptop automatically puts them up there... What have you tried till now? Perhaps I used another way, then I can give you my code and then you wouldn't need to mess with system properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I move my JMenuBar to the screen menu bar on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955638/how-do-i-move-my-jmenubar-to-the-screen-menu-bar-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set a System property to do so. The first example on http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html mentions to use `System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");` to put your menu into the menubar.